# Delete item from database -  ListView - Android

Tags: android, database, listview

```
public class DataViewActivity extends Activity{
SQLiteDatabase db;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
String dbTable = "users";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dbPop);

DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(DataViewActivity.this);
db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(dbTable, null, null, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);

String[] from = new String[] { "name","_id"};
int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from,
        to);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

How to implement onClick listener to this code to delete selected database row.  I don't know much about Android so for me its a learning curve.

Comment: Your question helped me a lot... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set `setOnItemClickListener` to your listview...

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            database.remove(id);//create removemethod in database class

        }
    });
```

**and in remove method**

```
    public void remove(long id){
        String string =String.valueOf(id);
        database.execSQL("DELETE FROM favorite WHERE _id = '" + string + "'");
    }
```

Comment: I have a little question. How to store `id` in Db to make your solution work? Should I put `integer primary key` or `integer primary key autoincrement` or `integer primary key autoincrement not null`?

Comment: integer primary key autoincrement

Comment: Thanks for the reply, after questioning you I had read in sqlite documentation that autoincrement decreases the speed of the db and it doesn't make any difference whether you write `integer primary key` or `integer primary key autoincrement`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos,long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      {
             TextView tv=(TextView)v;
     String s1=tv.getText().toString();
            //delete row
            String delgrp="DELETE FROM (tablename) WHERE  (row)='"+s1+"'";
    sdb.execSQL(delgrp);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListView.onListItemClick`, as  third parameter has `position`. `Position` is the entry returned by `Adpater.getItem(int)`. So when you click on a row of your `ListView`, the `ListView.onListItemClick` is fired. There you can retrieve your Adapter entry and use the info you need to delete the entry from the database.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
      // do something with the cursor
}
```