# How to delete the selected items from the list in android

Tags: java, android

I have database and I display the contents in a list using the `simple_list_item_checked` layout. Now I want to delete items that the user chooses from that list. How can I do so?
this is the xml activity:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_delete"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/delete"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_page_mySpace2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/theuserideaslist"
    android:background="@drawable/brain1"
    android:layout_below="@id/ib_delete"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

and this is the remove method they told me to put it my open helper:

```
public void removeIedas (long id) {
    String string = String.valueOf(id);

    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM name WHERE _id = '" + string + "'");
}
```

and this is my java class for the activity:

```
final MyOpenHelper myOpenHelper = new MyOpenHelper( getApplicationContext());
    final ListView theuserideaslist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theuserideaslist);

    ArrayList<String> n ;
    n = myOpenHelper.ShowTheUserIdeas();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext() , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked , n ) ;
    theuserideaslist.setAdapter(myadapter);
    theuserideaslist.setChoiceMode(2);

    final ImageButton ib_delete = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_delete);

    theuserideaslist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, final long id) {

            ib_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    myOpenHelper.removeIedas(id); //create removemethod in database class

                }
            });

        }
    });

  /*  ib_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            theuserideaslist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                  //  ArrayList database = null;
                    myOpenHelper.removeIedas(id); //create removemethod in database class

                }
            });
        }
    });*/
```

what i want is: when i click on `ib_delete` delete the checked items.
And I am sorry, i am still new.
Thank You.

Comment: Hi Somaya,
I am assuming you are using some java code to do this and simple_list_item_checked is an ArrayList or sort of it. Can you please share a quick snippet of the code where you are trying to achieve this so I can assist you better?
Thanks

Comment: Hello Aritra, i don't know i think it is not possible to share it in a comment here! what can i do? and really thank you for your help mr. Aritra

Comment: Hey no probs :-) But by the way did you try out @some user's answer? Did it work?

Comment: i am trying now but i have some problems, but still trying.. i will tell u guys when i done it :)

Comment: Ok sure lets do that

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I post it.. Ferdous and Aritre, i am sorry i was not know that i can edit the post! hope you  can help me now

Answer (score 1):

Use This:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         database.remove(id); //Create a remove method in your database class
     }
});
```

and in remove method:

```
public void remove(long id){
    String string = String.valueOf(id);
    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM favorite WHERE _id = '" + string + "'");
}
```

Collected from 
[this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684511/delete-item-from-database-listview-android)

***Update:***

**don't set onclick lister on the button**, in fact you probably want to remove an item from list view when it is clicked.

Assuming that your listView is the id for ListView of your Activity,

Here:

myDBHelper is an object of class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper  like

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//codes..

    public void DeleteFromDB(String d) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    String dm = "\"" + d + "\"";

    try {
        db.execSQL("delete from " + db_table + " where taskName=" + dm);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

   }
}
```

**Then use this in main activity :**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        myDBHelper.DeleteFromDB(arrayList.get(position));

        }
    });
```

Comment: okay, in **MyOpenHelper** when i create remove method, what to write instead of  _database_ ?

Comment: create an object of  `SQLiteDatabase` class, that is the database here.

Comment: excuse me but can i ask sth? now if i click on the item then it will be deleted or must i but the first code inside **button onClickListener ** ? i made it like how u give me but it says " the app has stopped"

Comment: @SomayaMig I have updated answer to make explanation easier, check it.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, but what must i write instead of `context` which is in **Toast** ? it is red.. i know that in `context` place we put the class name put it did not work too? my object from `SQLiteOpenHelper ` is **MyOpenHelper**, and the activity which the list in i named it **ShowTheUserIdeas** ?

Comment: `Context context;
    public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "dbName", null, version);
        this.context = context;
    }` the context you passed through main activity using getapplication context, use this context for making toast

Comment: what to write instead of `where taskName=`?
and i wrote the field's name that i want to to delete from instead of `delete from` is this right?

Comment: taskName is the field/column, from which you wanna delete your values

Comment: what about the `delete from`? shall I keep it ?

Comment: `delete from` is an sql query, so it is must needed to delete data